# Problem to save values with signal in django

Tags: django, django-signals

With this signal, i try to save the values on same table, but it save initial value (total_ht=0, total_tva=0, total_ttc=0) instead of values 10 20 30, and when i update the invoice without any changes, it s updated and it display the correct values.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    total_ht = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    total_tva = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    total_ttc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def calculate(self, save=False):

        total_ht = 0
        total_tva = 0
        total_ttc = 0

        for invoiceitem in invoiceitems:
            total_ht += 10
            total_tva += 20
            total_ttc += total_ht + total_tva

        totals = {
            'total_ht': total_ht,
            'total_tva': total_tva,
            'total_ttc': total_ttc,
        }

        for k,v in totals.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
            if save == True:
                self.save()
        return totals


def invoice_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.calculate(save=False)

pre_save.connect(invoice_pre_save, sender=Invoice)
```

Comment: Please do *not* save totals in the model. You can calculate the totals when necessary through [`.annotate(..)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). This is also more efficient since you can do this at the database side.

Comment: you mean just methods are sufficient ? in case of changes ? is there any other risks. thx

Comment: no annotations are sufficient. This also avoids *data duplication*, which often results in a lot of synchronization problems.